# Trying to use BGAppRefreshTask and getting error No task request with identifier <decode: missing data> has been scheduled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I kept getting the error

> `No task request with identifier <decode: missing data> has been scheduled`

in my debugger output so I decided to try running the example code provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks) and got the same error. I've tried multiple computers and Xcode versions, multiple example projects from different sources and nothing has worked.

My AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import BackgroundTasks

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
                
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: “redacted.identifier”, using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
        scheduleAppRefresh()
    }
    
     func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "redacted.identifier")
        
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("devices").document(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString).setData([
            "batteryLevel": UIDevice.current.batteryLevel*100
            ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("success")
                task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            }
        }
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
        }
    }
```

I am testing background fetch by running

```
e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"redacted.identifier"]
```

in the Xcode console, after which the error above occurs.

Console output:

```
Simulating launch for task with identifier redacted.identifier

No task request with identifier <decode: missing data> has been scheduled
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of potential issues:

- This happens when testing on the simulator. Use a physical device.
- Make sure your `Info.plist` has a “Permitted background task scheduler identifiers” (i.e. `BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers`) entry with the identifier for your background task.
- Make sure you set your breakpoint immediately after the `BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(...)` line and that you perform the `_simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier` after `submit` was called. I.e., make sure you are even getting to the `submit` call. (See next point.)
- Notably, the Apple example (and your example) are scheduling it in `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)`. But if you are using a `UIWindowSceneDelegate` (i.e. in your `SceneDelegate`), then the app delegate’s `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` is not called, but rather the scene delegate’s `sceneDidEnterBackground(_:)` is. I put the scheduling of the `BGAppRefreshTaskRequest` in the scene delegate’s `sceneDidEnterBackground(_:)`.

Comment: I have actually tested on 3 different physical devices and the same error happens on all 3.

Comment: Is your task identifier included in your plist? That results in a similar error.

Comment: Yes, my info.plist has the task identifier included under Permitted background task scheduler identifiers. I have noticed that if I click edit scheme and select "Launch due to a background fetch event", it works just fine. Does this mean the issue is simply with the testing and it's safe to release this as to the App Store?

Comment: I don't need that option in order for the `_simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier` to work. By the way, do you have a `SceneDelegate`? If so, it might not be hitting the scheduling of your `BGAppRefreshTaskRequest`. Make sure you're actually calling `submit. (See additional points in my answer above.)

Comment: @ConfuseIous - Otherwise, I might suggest you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), upload it somewhere, and I’m happy to see if I can reproduce your problem. Feel free to see [my MCVE](https://github.com/robertmryan/BGAppRefresh), which does not result in that “No task request with identifier <decode: missing data> has been scheduled” message (assuming I do this after `submit` was called, which is why I put the breakpoint where I did).

Comment: Thank you so much, the issue was that something in my scene delegate was preventing sceneDidEnterBackground from being called, I replaced the code with what you so kindly provided and it seems to be running just fine now. I have marked your answer as accepted, really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Rob Did this go any further? I’m getting a “Task with identifier <decode: missing data> is not currently being simulated” error message in the debug window.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. The above simulation process worked fine for me. Did you hit the breakpoint after `submit` and only then `_simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier`?

Comment: There is another potential cause that you've missed which tripped me up. Remember to add 'Background fetch' to the 'Background Modes' capability.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue when I tested on a Device.
Go to Device Settings > General > Background App Refresh and turn on Background App Refresh. This issue has gone after it.

Answer (score 5):

There is one another case that isn't mentioned in other answers, if you're trying to submit different or more than 1 refresh tasks you might be hitting the error case below. Issue is, currently the mentioned error isn't thrown in Xcode 13.1, so it looks like submitting request works, but basically it doesn't.

**Apple doc**: There can be a total of 1 refresh task and 10 processing tasks scheduled at any time. Trying to schedule more tasks returns *BGTaskScheduler.Error.Code.tooManyPendingTaskRequests.*

Comment: is this something that changed recently? I was using 1 refresh task and 1 processing task and the processing task wasn't ever running.  Putting the processing operating code inside the 1 refresh task now works, but using 1 refresh task and 1 processing task worked when I first wrote my background task code in January 21 

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `applicationDidEnterBackground`  is never get called, check it out (add breakpoint).

> ```
> func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
>     BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
>     scheduleAppRefresh()
> }
> ```

because of a scene-based configured lifecycle

If it's true, move your logic into SceneDelegate class

> ```
> func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
>     BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
>     scheduleAppRefresh()
> }
> ```